# Changing the content of dialog box based on the option selected from the drop down menu in Angular 8

Tags: angular8

I want to populate the content of dialogue box based on the option selected from the drop-down menu. Like if you are selecting Cat from the drop down, then the information about cat will be diaplayed in the dialog box. Likewise if Dog is selected then in the same dialogue box information about dog should be displayed.

Comment: I am complete novice in angular.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5cnqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Yes, I used that. My scenario is I have a "drop down box" and adjacent to that I have a button to open dialog box. The content should change as per the data selected from the drop down menu. I came to know that one way to do so is by using Behaviour subject but I am not sure how should I implement that here.

Comment: I have created a separate component for the dialog box.

Comment: I will have to post whole project there and also I don't have permission for that. Anyways thank you. I will have to figure that out myself I guess

Comment: you have to create a new project, and post a  minimal reproducible example